# Multiple CTE where clauses referece CTW column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

For example

```
WITH UserDetail (UserId, UserName)
AS
(
    SELECT TOP(10) U.UserId,U.UserName
    FROM UserTable U        
),
UserAction (ActionName,ActionType)
AS
(
    SELECT TOP(10) A.ActionName,A.ActionType
    FROM ActionTable A
    WHERE A.UserId = UserDetail.UserId // Is it possible to direct reference  
)
WHERE A.UserId = UserDetail.UserId
```

Can I direct doing this instead of joining of UserDetail inside my second CTE.

I am getting error of:

> multi-part of identifier "UserDetail.UserId" could not be found

In the CTE reference, is it possible to reference back to previous CTE without joining the CTE table? Or I am writing a wrong query

Comment: Are you trying to do an IN? I don't get how you're hoping to do an `=` when you're trying to do it on a table with multiple values without joining.
Why are you trying to do it without joining?

Comment: @Ben wanted to know whether any alternative way instead of joining the table up .

Comment: There are up to 10 rows in `UserDetail`. *Which* row's `UserId` are you trying to refer to? Do you see now why you want/need the join?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use like this - with joining the `UserDetail` cte

```
WITH UserDetail (UserId, UserName)
AS
(
    SELECT TOP(10) U.UserId,U.UserName
    FROM UserTable U        
),
UserAction (ActionName,ActionType)
AS
(
    SELECT TOP(10) A.ActionName,A.ActionType
    FROM ActionTable A inner join UserDetail
    on A.UserId = UserDetail.UserId
)
```

OR you can use subquery

```
WITH UserDetail (UserId, UserName)
    AS
    (
        SELECT TOP(10) U.UserId,U.UserName
        FROM UserTable U        
    ),
    UserAction (ActionName,ActionType)
    AS
    (
        SELECT TOP(10) A.ActionName,A.ActionType
        FROM ActionTable A
        where A.UserId in (select UserDetail.UserId from UserDetail)
    )
```

Comment: is it possible to do it without joining ?

Comment: no, without joining it is not possible, but you can use subquery to refer this - but direct it not possible @abccba